# column space of A is the answer to Ax=v

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

What is the proof for the theorem mentioned here?
What is the intuition behind the proof?
https://www.math.upenn.edu/~moose/240S2013/slides7-22.pdf

[image]

Comment: This is the definition of column space. All it says is that the column space of a matrix A is the set of all vectors v for which there exists a vector x such that Ax =v.

Comment: Can you explicitely write the theorem you refer to? There are several theorems in the linked slides.

Comment: So basically, how can I prove that Ax=v has a solution if and only if v is in the column space of A?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is to spell out rpa's comment/explanation above:

Write the matrix as a 'row of columns': 
$$ A = \left(c_1, \cdots , c_n \right).$$
By definition, the column space is the set (in fact, the vector space) of vectors $v$ which can be written as a linear combination of the columns: it is the set of $v$, for which there are  *some*  $x_1,\cdots,x_n \in {\mathbb R}$, such that 
$$ v = x_1c_1+ \cdots + x_nc_n.$$
(The $x_i$ depend of course on which $v$!)

Now, write the $x_1,\cdots, x_n$ as a  (column) vector $x$:
$$ x = \pmatrix{x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n}. $$
Then, by definition of matrix multiplication,
$$ A x = (c_1, \ldots , c_n)\, x = (c_1, \ldots , c_n)\pmatrix{x_1 \\ \vdots \\ x_n}= x_1c_1+ \cdots + x_nc_n.$$

So $v = Ax $ for some $x$ — i.e., "the linear system $Ax =v$ is consistent" — precisely if there are  some $x_1,\cdots,x_n \in {\mathbb R}$ such that $v = x_1c_1+ \cdots + x_nc_n$ — i.e., precisely "if $v$ is in the column space of $A$."

Hope this helps!